# how to check array keys are exits in multidimensional array using twig templates in html

Tags: php, html

I am working on functionality in which i have html,php pages and data are passed from php to html..Those data values are displayed in HTML page using twig templates.

Now these twig templates are creating problem in my code.

I have a multidimensional array as key and value pair($details) and an array of objects($ids) in which some elements will match keys of $details array.

For Example:

In php:

```
$details=array([21]=>array(['name']=>A,['addrs']=>XX),    
               [22]=>array(['name']=>A,['addrs']=>XX));
$ids = array([50] => Test Object ([id] => 11,[name]=>xx),
             [51] => Test Object ([id] => 21,[name]=>yy),
             [52] => Test Object ([id] => 22,[name]=>zz));

echo $renderer->render(
    'sample.html', array(
        'title' => $title,
        'user' => $username,
        'details' => $details,
        'ids'=>$ids));
```

sample.html:

```
{% for i in ids %}
    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
    <td>{{details[i.id]}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Here `<td>{{details[i.id]}}</td>` throwing error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Runtime' with message 'Key "11" for array with keys "21, 22" does not exist in "sample.html`

Can you tell me how to fix this error and display `details` with only exists key ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're mixing up Twig and Django... Django is a python framework.

Comment: Sry..I dont know what it is exactly..I am very new to these templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your key exists :

```
{% for i in ids %}
    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
    {% if details[i.id] is defined %}
        <td>{{details[i.id]}}</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using Twig can we find substring like this `substr($name[$i],0,3) != 'tmp')`?

Comment: We can find substrings thanks `in` filter : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator